# Symfony2 Forms: is it possible to bind a form in an "unconventional way"?

Tags: forms, symfony

Imagine this scenario: in our company there is an employee that "play" around graphic,css,html and so on.
Our new project will born under symfony2 so we're trying some silly - but "real" - stuff (like authentication from db, submit data from a form and persist it to db and so on..)

**The problem**

As far i know, learnt from symfony2 "book" that i found on the site ([you can find it here)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html), there is an "automated" way for creating and rendering forms:

1) Build the form up into a controller in this way

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
       ->add('task','text'),
       ->add('dueDate','date'),
       ->getForm();

return $this->render('pathToBundle:Controller:templateTwig',
        array('form'=>$form->createview());
```

2) Into `templateTwig` render the template

```
{{ form_widget(form) }} // or single rows method
```

3) Into a controller (the same that have a route where you can submit data), take back submitted information

```
if($rquest->getMethod()=='POST'){
 $form->bindRequest($request);
 /* and so on */
}
```

**Return to scenario**

Our graphic employee don't want to access controllers, write php and other stuff like those. So he'll write a twig template with a "unconventional" (from symfony2 point of view, but conventional from HTML point of view) method:

```
/* into twig template */
<form action="{{ path('SestanteUserBundle_homepage') }}" method="post" name="userForm">
    <div>
        USERNAME: <input type="text" name="user_name" value="{{ user.username}}"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        EMAIL: <input type="text" name="user_mail" value="{{ user.email }}"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ id }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="modifica i dati">
  </form>
```

Now, if into the controller that handle the submission of data we do something like that

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){ // sono arrivato per via di un submit, quindi devo modificare i dati prima di farli vedere a video
      $defaultData = array('message'=>'ho visto questa cosa in esempio, ma non capisco se posso farne a meno');
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
           ->add('user_name','text')
           ->add('user_mail','email')
           ->add('user_id','integer')
           ->getForm();
      $form->bindRequest($request); //bindo la form ad una request
      $data = $form->getData(); //mi aspetto un'array chiave=>valore
      /* .... */
```

We expected that `$data` will contain an array with key,value from the submitted form.
We found that it isn't true. After googling for a while and try with other "bad" ideas, we're frozen into that.

So, if you have a "graphic office" that can't handle directly php code, how can we interface from form(s) to controller(s) ?

**UPDATE**
It seems that Symfony2 use a different convention for form's field name and lookup once you've submitted that.
In particular, if my form's name is `addUser` and a field is named `userName`, the field's name will be `AddUser[username]` so maybe it have a "dynamic" lookup method that will extract form's name, field's name, concat them and lookup for values.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Symfony2 to set the name of a form field, though I don't suggest it: `$formBuilder->add('dummyfield', 'text', array( 'attr' => array('name' => 'yournamehere') ) );`

Alternatively (also a bad idea), you can do this, which won't even let you use the form API: `$this->getRequest()->get('whatever_the_field_name_is');`

OR you can hackily add elements to the request based on the Sf2 generated names before binding it (copying the values that exist).

OR you can make use of the bind method of the form component (instead of bindRequest) as documented [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_bind).

But seriously...just use the formbuilder api. Your life will be easier, and isn't that what a framework is for? :)

Comment: This was I looking for and i suppose that those couples of methods, are the "best" alternative though they are not the best (or even good) practise. However, we'll use the formBuilder and whatever is related to it, as i told before: is just for a matter of curiosity

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 2 is based on twig as templating language. Let him use it :

```
{{ form_label(form.field) }}
```

will generate something like this :

```
<label for="field">field</label>
```

You can use all the available functions in order to render the form :

```
{{ form_label() }}
{{ form_widget() }}
{{ form_errors() }}
```

If you want to customize what is rendered by those functions, you can override twig templates as defined in the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Otherwise if you really want to something **ugly**, you can go for this kind of syntax :

```
{{ myform.vars.value.myField }}
```

Comment: I know that this is a possibility and ok, we are orientated to this solution since before asking the question. But i think that's impossible that there isn't a way for declare in explicit what I want into my form.. So, we're still trying but maybe we're close to the solution. Thank you for the answer, but isn't what i'm asking for.

Comment: I am aware that it isn't a solution but what you are trying to do is not the right way to do it. You are trying to adapt your code to what your designer is asking you. Normally, your designer should adapt to what your code/framework is offering. Not the opposit.

Comment: you're asbsolutely right, but i'm asking that question because, to me, isn't possible that a framework with those potentiality can't be used with a "from scratch" form definition DIRECTLY into twig. Obviously we'll follow what framework offers to us, but i was only curious to know about that "exotic" solution.